# QGraphicsTextItem is too slow for long paragraphs

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

I`m trying to make simple text editor with Qt. I plan to use QGraphicsScene due to its greater opportunities than QTextEdit, QTextBrowser, etc. So, to begin with, I have prepared the simple example with QGraphicsTextItem:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView view;
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    QGraphicsTextItem *text = new QGraphicsTextItem;

    text->setTextWidth(1020);
    text->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
    text->setFocus();

    scene->addItem(text);

    view.setScene(scene);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The application works well with formatted text: containg paragraphs and different styles. But when I try to write one long paragraph, it starts freezing already at ~200k symbols, which is quite small for my tasks. I assume this is due to the fact that Qt divides complex text into parts internally, but doesn`t do this for simple text of the same style. I have tried many flags but not a single piece of advice to speed up the QGraphicsScene helped me. Could you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: QTextBrowser is just an extension of QTextEdit. And while the QGraphicsView framework certainly allows features that otherwise QTextEdit wouldn't provide, it also makes things much more complex, especially in terms of computation, since it adds a further layer of complexity, especially about geometry computation and drawing: every item has its own transformation chain, no matter if it's actually *transformed* or not, and that increases computation requirements for large texts. Besides, 200 thousand symbols are quite a lot for a single paragraph, and I wouldn't be surprised if even the »

Comment: » standard QTextEdit would struggle a bit with that amount of characters in a single QTextBlock. That said, are you completely sure that what you need actually requires the graphics view framework? Because if you only need that to add custom "objects" (resizable images, drawings, etc), maybe you should consider the [QTextObjectInterface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextobjectinterface.html) API.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your advice, I agree that 200k symbols is quite a lot, but e.g., windows notepad or wordpad can easily handle such amount of symbols, maybe we can create [QTextBlock](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html) more often and that will help? We choose graphics view framework because it allows us to add complex objects on scene e.g., video player and I`m not sure that we can find substitute for [QGraphicsScene::addWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) in that regard.

Comment: Technically, with the QTextObjectInterface you could add anything. A video player may be a bit challenging but not impossible, it's just a matter of properly manage the geometries and synchronizing scrolling. The fact that notepad/wordpad can manage it is irrelevant, they use a different "toolkit" and may use specific optimization when dealing with "fringe cases". The QTextDocument API is intended for *generic* usage, and depending on the situation may require tweaking, which, for example, is what QPlainTextEdit does by means of QPlainTextDocumentLayout, which is optimized for very large text.

Comment: The first thing to check is to ensure if a standard QTextEdit (which uses the common QTextDocument layout) can manage such character amount without issues. If it does, then it may depend on the graphics view aspects I mentioned above, so you may need to check its internal implementation by studying the Qt sources and then consider adding optimizations for large amounts of text, possibly by caching portions of the layout or the overall geometry (to prevent unnecessary computations), delaying geometry changes or even use *images* that render lines of block of lines.